# How to replace google maps with a background image

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps

I hope you can help me. Google map does not work and I would like to replace google maps with a background image. How do I do that?

Are there some who can show me? I´m not so good at php and it is some code in wordpress.

My code:

```
<section id="contact">
    <!-- map -->
    <div id="gmap_canvas"></div> 
    <?php
    global $tlazya_evential;
    $glat = $tlazya_evential['map_lat'];
    $glng = $tlazya_evential['map_lng'];
    $gzoom = $tlazya_evential['map_zoom'];
    $gct1 = $tlazya_evential['map_marker_title'];
    $gct2 = $tlazya_evential['map_marker_content'];
    if ((isset($tlazya_evential['map_lat']) && $tlazya_evential['map_lat'] != '') && (isset($tlazya_evential['map_lng']) && $tlazya_evential['map_lng'] != '')) {
        ?>
        <?php echo do_shortcode('[rms-googlemap lat="' . esc_attr($glat) . '" lng="' . esc_attr($glng) . '" zoom="' . esc_attr($gzoom) . '" contents="' . esc_html($gct1) . '" contents2="' . esc_html($gct2) . '"]'); ?>
        <?php
    } else {
        ?>
         <?php echo do_shortcode('[rms-googlemap lat="56.171243" lng="9.556884" zoom="16" contents="ThemeonLab" contents2="Quality Template Provide"]'); ?>
<?php } ?>    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <?php if(isset($tlazya_evential['address_info']) && $tlazya_evential['address_info'] != ''){ ?>
                <div class="contact">
                    <?php
                    global $tlazya_evential;
                    if (isset($tlazya_evential['title_info']) && $tlazya_evential['title_info'] != '') {
                        echo '<h2 class="uppercase">' . esc_html($tlazya_evential['title_info']) . '</h2>';
                    }
                    ?>
                    <?php
```

Comment: What happens when you just remove the `<div id="gmap_canvas"></div>` and add a background image to the `<section>` (in your CSS)?

Comment: Thanks for the help! It works now.
I remove <div id="gmap_canvas"></div> and insert this code: <html><img src="http://digitalkonference.dk/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Fotolia_99524285_m2.jpg" width="100%" height="598" /></html>